# Symfony: upload several files with extra fields in same form

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I have an attachment form type, like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('file_upload', 'file', array('required' => false,
                                       'mapped'   => false,
                                       'label'    => false))
    ->add('filename', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'))
    ->add('comment', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Comment'))
;
```

And I have a main entity, which has a collection of attachments, like this:

```
->add('attachments', 'collection', array('type'         => new AttachmentType(),
                                              'allow_add'    => true,
                                              'allow_delete' => true,
                                              'by_reference' => false
                                             ))
```

In my *MainEntityController* I want to loop through uploaded files and I want to be able to relate each file with its corresponding name and comment, is this possible? I'm not even able to loop through files, as I don't really know how to debug form (`file_upload` field does not appear in profiler).

This is my failing controller code:

```
$attachments = $editForm['attachments']->getData();

foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
{
    $ficheros = $attachment['file_upload']->getData();

    foreach ($ficheros as $fich)
    {
         error_log("Upload " . $fich->getClientOriginalName());
```

I get error:

> Error: Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\Attachment as array 
>   $ficheros = $attachment['file_upload']->getData();

So,

How can I loop through uploaded files?
Can I relate each uploaded file with its corresponding name and comment?
Or should I opt for some other solution, like and ajax file by file upload?

Comment: I got it, will post a solution shortly

Comment: $ficheros is an AttachmentType entity not an array, you've already got the entity you want and just have to access the fields directly, but it sounds like you already figured that out :)